# Accessing Key In Json - Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, key

I'm trying to access the keys "stamp_ids" in this [json](http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/stamps.json)

This is my code

```
def dload_stamps
        path = "#{JPATH}" + "#{URLS["stamps"]}" #the json
        content = @tools.get_decode(path); #fetch and decode the json
        content.each do |index|
            index.each do |indextwo|
                    indextwo.each do |stamp|
                        pp stamp
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

This is as far as I'm getting http://prntscr.com/3snxyf I'm not able to access "stamp_id"

Help?

Comment: Why do not use [json](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to require the JSON and Open-URI gems, and just use this code snippet to parse the JSON to an Ruby object (in this case an array of Ruby hashes):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
uri = "http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/stamps.json"


parsed_ruby_object = JSON.parse(open(uri).read)
```

Then you can go one by one through each collection and fetch stamps (i've just written an example for getting the first of the arrays:

```
parsed_ruby_object.first['stamps'].map do |member|
  member['stamp_id']
end
```

**EDITED:**
To take the stamp_ids from each array:

```
parsed_ruby_object.map do |array_member|
  array_member['stamps'].map do |member|
    member['stamp_id']
  end
end.flatten
```

The code above will get you all the `stamp_ids` in all arrays.

Comment: That's pretty much what I do, except the mapping part. Is there any other way like what I provided? I want to access them all at once. Sorry if I sound stupid, but I've never played around with multiple arrays in Ruby before when decoding a json. Something like this maybe? I wrote this in Perl http://pastebin.com/Um3sa7LH

Comment: I've edited the answer for fetching ALL the stamp_ids.